# Zend2 on submit POST gets 500 error and blank page

Tags: php, post, zend-framework2

I have two servers each running a modified version of ZF2 Skeleton Application.

- Server1:8080 - REST API that just returns JSON
- Server2:8081 - Web client serving our customer

I am getting the famed 'White Screen of Death' in Server 2.

1. Visit a user's webpage via the route /%s - %s being their username, everything looks fine
2. User is presented with a status text box and submit button
3. I click submit with some text, and get the White Screen

   I recently added an ability to POST a status update to the page.

   server2:80 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2014:21:52:27 -0700] "POST /myusername HTTP/1.1" 500 357 "server1:8081/hwy9nightkid" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"

Notice the log file is citing port 80..  not sure why.. but just to double check I looked at my endpoint.. it's working fine for everything else (user's profile data displays)

```
zf2-server2/module/Api/src/Api/Client/ApiClient.php:    protected static $endpointHost = 'http://server2.local:8080';
```

This site was working great until I added this module's ability to POST data to Server2..  any ideas on how to debug this the Zend way?  I'm new so I may just start littering the system with logging information to trace where it's truly stuck, maybe grab an IDE like PHPStorm if that would help.

I know for a fact the POST is received by the Server 1.. my guess is something happened processing that data.. and a 500 error was returned instead, but shouldn't that give me a nice looking error page???

**Update & progress with 500 Error**

In order to debug, I used an application called Postman

```
 www.getpostman.com
```

Thanks to this utility for Chrome, I create a simple POST to my service and found an error message was being returned wrapped in JSON.

```
 Error 500 : Table 'tablename' doesn't exist in db.
```

I'm going to look up how to properly handle errors / json responses that are unexpected.. and how to properly re-route my client to an error page.

**Update TL;DR - Seems my Server2 Web Client is failing to either Log this error AND OR display a 500 error page.**

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: See update, I used POSTMAN to get this directly from Server1... so issue was that Server2 failed to react well..